# accessing method in typescript

Tags: typescript, datatable

I want to call the getPopupWindowName method in the datatable class.
The problem is on datatable class the page is type so it not allowing me to call the getPopupWindowName  method. I am very new to typescript so don't know how exactly it's done
I have a page as below

```
 import BasePage from '../BasePage';
import PageHeaderRight from '../PageHeaderRight';
import DataTable from '../shared/DataTable';
import DateCalendarInput from '../shared/DateCalendarInput';

 export default class FXOptionsPage extends BasePage {
  pageControls: PageHeaderRight<FXOptionsPage>;
  constructor() {
  super();
  this.pageControls = new PageHeaderRight<FXOptionsPage>(this);
 }
  startDate() {
   return new DateCalendarInput('mainform', 'a_von');
  }
 getDataTable(): DataTable<FXOptionsPage> {
 return new DataTable<FXOptionsPage>(this, 'TableData');
 }
 getPopupWindowName() {
 return 'OPgrafik';
  }
  }
```

I want to access the  getPopupWindowName in following code

```
import ContractSecuritiesPage from '../TT/ContractSecuritiesPage';
import CreditLinesPage from '../TT/CreditLinesPage';
import FXOptionsPage from '../TT/FXOptionsPage';
import ChartPage from './ChartPage';
import ChartPopup from './ChartPopup';
import DataTableToolbar from './DataTableToolbar';
 import DetailsPopup from './DetailsPopup';
export default class DataTable<Page>  {
tableID: string;
 page: Page;

constructor(page: Page, tableID: string) {
this.tableID = tableID;
this.page = page;
 }
 clickDetailButton(): DetailsPopup<Page> {
 const buttonSelector = `tbody tr td`;
  this.getDataTableRootNode().element(buttonSelector).click();

  return new DetailsPopup(this.page, this.page.getDetailsPopupWindowName()(Here it say can't find methon on type page));
}
```

Comment: If you need to use a method of the class `FXOptionsPage`, you have to create an instance first.

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of the variable`page`.

```
export default class DataTable<FXOptionsPage>  {
 page: FXOptionsPage;
 ...
}
```

Comment: This class datatable is called from various places so I can't change the type to particular type. The type page is defined during run time